# How to disable the default context menu of react native webview, and call a react prop instead of native one?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to disable the default context menu that pops up on selecting text inside a webview, and instead handle this event from javascript side.

I added the following code in `RNCWebview.m` after some initial research,

```js
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"From native side");
   return NO;
}
```

and then passed a `onSelection` prop from where I rendered my component. I gave console.logs in my node modules and got this object as props to the webview

```
{"cacheEnabled": true, "javaScriptEnabled": true, "onSelection": [Function onSelection], "originWhitelist": ["http://*", "https://*"], "source": {"uri": "https://www.google.com"}, "style": {"height": 500}, "useSharedProcessPool": true}
```

But I am not sure how to handle this function and call it from objective-c code. But still the context menu shows up when I select some text in the webview and the `onSelection` prop is not getting called.

I am sure I am missing some link here. Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution for this. I modified the code `RNCWebView.m` and `RNCWebViewManager.m` to block the `onSelection` event and by implementing the following code.

```c
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
```

This disabled the default context menu inside web view. Then using `injectJavascript` prop of the webview I added an event listener to observe `selectionChange` event and respond to it with a custom function.

Comment: how did you modify `RNCWebView.m` and `RNCWebViewManager.m`. Can you give an example code please

Comment: can you help me

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have access to that code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For stop menuContext, you can add an eventListener for onselect event in order to use preventDefault in the code of you html in your WebView component, but onselect can only be used in [input and textarea tags](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp).

Comment: I want to pass the selection event info back to javascript side to handle it.